# RecyclerView Glide preloading?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have a gallery app that uses a `RecyclerView` in conjunction with `Glide` to accomplish scrolling through an image album but I'm finding that if my album has a lot of images (100+), the `RecyclerView` fails to load images smoothly. This is what I am experiencing:

[image: GIF of my gallery app]

Is there a way to `preload` these images or compress them into a thumbnail size so that the scrolling appears more seamless? The glide documentation shows some examples of accomplishing this for images that are fetched from the web but all of the images I am fetching are from local storage.

This is how I am displaying the images within my RecyclerView adapter's onBindViewHolder():

```
        Glide.with(this)
        .load(myImageUri())
        .apply(new RequestOptions()
        .centerCrop()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE))
        .into(myImageView);
```

Comment: Load only thumbnail not full image . And Use `DiskCacheStrategy.ALL`

Answer (score 0):

You can use .thumbnail(0.5f) for preview image before it fully load, here 0.5f is 2 times smaller than original size.See below code

```
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(myImageUri())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                .centerCrop()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE))
                .into(myImageView);`
```